# Вопрос стилей в css

Tags: css, style

Есть главный блок, в котором есть еще 3 блока, хотелось бы их расположить в строку и строго по центру, по вертикали.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <p>
      Some text
    </p>
  </div>
    <div class="block">
    <p>
      Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text
    </p>
  </div>
    <div class="block">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-8/128/Accept-icon.png" alt="#">
  </div>
</div>
```

Для примера [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ropxw2tb/)

Нужно так же, чтобы бордер оставался одинаковой высоты, подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container{
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    position:relative;
    height:500px;
}

.block{
    width: 23%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-left: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <p>
      Some text
    </p>
  </div>
    <div class="block">
    <p>
      Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text
    </p>
  </div>
    <div class="block">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-8/128/Accept-icon.png" alt="#">
  </div>
</div>
```